# How to Take Exception Caught Log in Visual Studio in Mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

My application debugged in mac. There was a `NullReference Exception` occurs in my application.

I don't know how to take the log of exception in macBook. How to take the exception caught log in macbook?

Comment: You can see the output in the "Application Output" at the right bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Logs can be found by browsing to the Help > Open Log Directory menu item